# Insert, update or alter column in postgres when working with to_char

Tags: postgresql, insert-update, postgresql-9.4, insert-into

What i have;

3 tables in postgres 9.4. Table 1 is the main table tables 2 and 3 contain some additional data (an update multiplier) which is quarterly (eg. Q1 2017 formatted as varchar). Table 1 has a date of transaction in date format along with a price paid column. I've added a column called 'quarters' to populate with new data which will be stored as varchar.

What i want to do;

Generate a quartely column in table 1, which i can do using

```
SELECT to_char(dateoftransfer, '"Q"Q YYYY') as quarters
FROM  table_1;
```

If i then try;

```
UPDATE table_1 (quarters)
SELECT to_char(dateoftransfer, '"Q"Q YYYY') as quarters
FROM  table_1;
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "quarters"
LINE 1: (quarters)
     ^
```

Should i be using COPY or INSERT INTO in place? The reason i want the column in table 1 is so that i can generate an update price column in table 1 by using a WHERE statement to find the correct multiplier. Its an inflation adjustment calculation.

Comment: Your syntax for the `UPDATE` command is wrong. Please see the manual for the correct syntax: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET quarters = to_char(dateoftransfer, '"Q"Q YYYY');
```